# Can a Muslim Restaurateur‎ keep his restaurant open during the daytime in Ramadhan?

Tags: sawm, non-muslim-countries

I live in a non-Muslim country and I see that even during Ramadhan some Muslim restaurateur‎s keep their restaurants open for non-Muslims during the fasting hours. Is this allowed?

In line with the same question, a Muslim brother has a shop and he keeps a drinking water dispenser outside his shop so that thirsty passers-by can slake their thirst. He does this solely for gaining Allah's pleasure. Would it be allowed for him to do this during Ramadhan?

What are the approaches if the shop is in a Muslim country and a non-Muslim country.

Jazakallahu khairan.

Answer (score 1):

There might be a number of valid reasons why a muslim is not fasting during Ramazan. So exceptions are mentioned in Quran. I don't see any restaurant being open during fasting time in Muslim majority countries. For non Muslim countries, there is no reason to close the restaurant.